# How can I delete row in an Excel file with power automate?

Tags: excel, power-automate, delete-row

I have a flow that reads rows from an Excel file and adds them to a table in Sharepoint. I need,after creating the row on Sharepoint, to delete the row on the Excel file. Alternatively, I am also fine with deleting everything at the end of processing. The size of the table in the Excel file should remain the same. Is there any way to delete the row without changing the size of the table in the Excel file?

I have tried deleting the row but it also shortens the size of the table.

Comment: Set the value of each cell in the row to "" ?

Answer (score 0):

I'd use Office Scripts.

This is any extremely basic script that will do exactly that ...

```
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook, tableName: string) {
    let table = workbook.getTable(tableName);
    table.getRangeBetweenHeaderAndTotal().clear(ExcelScript.ClearApplyTo.all);
}
```

It has the parameter of the table name so you can use it generically over any workbook and depending the size of your table, it will be quicker and a lot easier than looping using the standard Excel PowerAutomate operations for updating rows.

If you've never used Office Scripts before, here are some starting points ...

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/scripts/overview/excel

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/scripts/develop/power-automate-integration

Comment: Thanks Skin, I never used Office Scripts on the Flow. I'll see your link. 
Kind regards